# Binary Search Vietnamese word from array string in java android

Tags: android, database, android-listview, binary-search

I am making an android dictionary Vietnam - English (over 20,000 entries).
In my application contain edittext and Listview.
To search item in my listview, i use Binary Search.
But the problem is with the search method and Vietnamese, it doesn't search well
some words it can find, some it can't.

Following is my search code to find word by prefix when edittext change.

```
public void searchWords(String[] words, String prefix)
    {
        int first = 0, last = words.length - 1;
        int mid = 0;

        while (first <= last)
        {
            mid = (first + last) / 2;
           int c = prefix.compareTo(words[mid]);
            if (c == 0)
            {
                first = mid;    // first indicates the beginning
                break;
            }
            if (c > 0)
                first = mid + 1;
            else
                last = mid - 1;
        }

        int i;
        for (i = first; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].startsWith(prefix))
            {
             pos=i;
             break;
            }
        }

        lv.setSelection(pos);
 //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and onTextchange code i call my method like this:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         searchWords(w,s.toString());

       }
```

and this is how i load my entries from database to array:

```
d=handle.retrieve();

    if(d.moveToFirst())
     {
         do
         {
             w[ii++]=d.getString(1);

         }while(d.moveToNext());

     }
```

So, what should i do to make my search working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Binary Search with "compareTo()" works only with SORTED words (or sorted Strings, i.e. sorted in alphabetic sequence -regardless of language). Meaning: Array starts with A, AA, AAA,... and ends with z, zz, zzz...Btw, UPPER case before lower case. Example:

```
String[] seq = {"Ape", "Bird", "Donkey", "Eagle", "Fish", "Gnu", "Horse", "Koala"};
String[] ran = {"Gnu", "Koala", "Horse", "Fish", "Bird", "Donkey", "Eagle", "Ape"};
String[] queries = {"Eagle", "Bird", "Donkey", "Fish", "Ape", "Horse", "Eagle", "Gnu"};
// binarySearch with random[] will produce unpredictable results when prefix starts with
// a word that is either after "Bird" or "Ape" or "Gnu" 
for (String s : queries) {
   System.out.println("Random: BS for " + s + " = " + binarySearch(ran, s));
}
//
// binarySearch with sequence[] will produce correct results whatever prefix is.
for (String s : queries) {
        System.out.println("Sequence: BS for " + s + " = " + binarySearch(seq, s));
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static int binarySearch(String[] words, String value) {
    return binarySearch(words, value, 0, words.length - 1);
}
//
public static int binarySearch(String[] words, String value, int min, int max) {
    if (min > max) {
        return -1;
    }

    int mid = (max + min) / 2;
    if (words[mid].equals(value)) return mid;
    if(words[mid].compareTo(value) > 0)
        return binarySearch(words, value, min, mid - 1);
    return binarySearch(words, value, mid + 1, max);
}
```